# How do I set the correct time on Centos 7?

Tags: centos, date, time, timezone, ntp

I have the minimal install of Centos 7 on my PC (not virtual box). I have spent the last few hours trying to figure out how to set up the correct time. I am still fast by one hour. After spending several hours doing Google searches, the following is what I have done so far in order:

1. `yum install ntp`
2. Changed `centos.pool.ntp.org` to `us.pool.ntp.org` for server 0, 1, 2, 3 in my `/etc/ntp.conf` file
3. Added "**restrict** *my_ip* **netmask** *my_netmask* **nomodify notrap**" to my `/etc/ntp.conf` file
4. `timedatectl set-local-rtc 0`
5. `um install tzdata` (to make sure my timezones are correct and up to date)
6. `timedatectl set-timezone "America/Los_Angeles"` (I live in CA)

After all this, when I type date at the prompt, I see the correct date, but the time shown is one hour ahead. How can I fix this? The output of running `timedatectl` is as follows:

```
      Local time: Mon 2016-09-12 06:02:25 PDT
  Universal time: Mon 2016-09-12 13:02:25 UTC
        RTC time: Mon 2016-09-12 13:02:25
       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at 
             Sun 2016-03-13 01:59:59 PST
             Sun 2016-03-13 03:00:00 PDT
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
             Sun 2016-11-06 01:59:59 PDT
             Sun 2016-11-06 01:00:00 PST
```

Comment: When you ran `timedatectl` in your question, what was the real time? Please would you [add that to the question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/309614/edit).

Comment: Ntp will not make huge changes in time so chances are the one hour difference you have can't be fixed directly by ntp.  Try setting the date and time correctly using the `date` command, and then watch and see if your time is maintained correctly.

Comment: I guess I could use date command to set everything manually...wouldn't that defeat the purpose of using an external server to set the date and the time accurately on my machine? When I ran the datetimectl yesterday, the real time was 5:02PM.

Comment: if you don't want to know the current time in order to run `date`, consider `ntpdate -b us.pool.ntp.org`. "This is useful in some cases to set the clock initially before starting the NTP daemon ntpd."

Comment: In addition to @JeffSchaller you may need to temporarily stop the ntp daemon before running the `ntpdate` command he suggested. OTW you may get a port in use error.